# How to find an item in an object of deep nested arrays in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am currently on Inertia JS along with Vue 3, I need to show the name as the heading of each navigated component within my `Layout`. I need to find an item within deep nested object of arrays so when ever the user is navigated to any other component, the name of the component is displayed as the heading.

But this method to find an item within the object of arrays is not working, please if someone can spare some time to have a look at it and help me.

```
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const internalRoutes = reactive({
    mainMenu: [
        {
            name: 'Dashboard',
            href: route('dashboard'),
            icon: 'Squares2X2Icon',
            current: 'Dashboard',
        },
        {
            name: 'Users',
            icon: 'UsersIcon',
            current: false,
            children: [
                { name: 'Engineering', href: '#', current: false },
                { name: 'Human Resources', href: '#', current: false },
                {
                    name: 'Customer Success',
                    href: '#',
                    current: false,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Reports',
            href: '#',
            icon: 'ChartPieIcon',
            current: false,
        },
        {
            name: 'Projects',
            icon: 'FolderIcon',
            current: false,
            children: [
                { name: 'GraphQL API', href: '#' },
                { name: 'iOS App', href: '#' },
                { name: 'Android App', href: '#' },
                { name: 'Customer Portal', href: '#' },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Calendar',
            href: '#',
            icon: 'CalendarIcon',
            current: false,
        },
        {
            name: 'Documents',
            href: '#',
            icon: 'DocumentDuplicateIcon',
            current: false,
        },
    ],
    userMenu: [
        {
            name: 'Profile',
            href: route('profile.edit'),
            current: 'Profile/Edit',
        },
        {
            name: 'Sign Out',
            href: route('logout'),
            method: 'post',
            as: 'button',
        },
    ],
    settingsMenu: [
        {
            name: 'Organization',
            current: true,
            href: '#',
        },
        {
            name: 'Access Control',
            href: route('access_control'),
            current: 'Settings/AccessControl/Index',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'Users',
                    href: route('users.index'),
                    current: false,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Roles',
                    href: route('roles.index'),
                    current: false,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Permissions',
                    href: route('permissions.index'),
                    current: false,
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
})

const pageHeader = computed(
    () =>
        internalRoutes?.find(
            (item) => item.current === usePage().component
        )?.name
)
```

Comment: If it's nested and you don't know the max depth then you will need to use recursion for this. Do you know how deep the nesting will go?

Comment: @bassxzero This will be the max, not more than this, how can I workaround with it. If the one which I am asking is not possible, can you guide me another way to push the heading from each component when ever it is navigated to, please any help?

Comment: Since this is only two levels you can just used a nested loop to.

Comment: Wherever you are reading `href` attribute, that would be the place to read `name` as well and pass it in props. Or else you can store at that point in some central store and read from there in all components. Or you can recreate a map of route as key and component name as value. You can ready that map from every component using `window.location.pathname`

Comment: @heyitsvajid Sorry couldn't reply any sooner, can you please elaborate or show me the code piece structure, it would be really great.

Comment: @bassxzero Can you please help me with the code structure for such condition. Really thank you for your time!